# Count occurrences of a field for each group?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing a pretty complicated query, and I'm slipping at the very last step.

I have managed to get this far:

```
id  refid           system_id   item_description_id   system_component_id   current_status
711 4fb62cece5313   49          NULL                  711                   RUNNING
712 4fb62cece547d   49          NULL                  712                   STOPPED
713 4fb62cece5616   50          NULL                  713                   RUNNING
714 4fb62cece5803   50          NULL                  714                   STOPPED
716 4fb62cece5ab8   51          NULL                  716                   RUNNING
```

These are the current statuses of every component of each system. What comes next is to group them by system and count the occurrences that are 'STOPPED'.

My problem is that some systems will not have any rows with 'STOPPED', or any rows at all if the system has never been updated. Yet, I still have to get them as part of the result. Just grouping them by system works for all but these two cases, in which the resulting value is '1' even though there are no stopped components at all.

How can I make a query that will return something like this:

```
system_id    status_count
49           1
50           1
51           0
```

And not:

```
system_id    status_count
49           1
50           1
51           1
```

With the above table?

Comment: you got your answer but you can still try my querry if it works too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `SUM(boolean)`, like this:

```
select system_id, 
  sum(current_status = 'STOPPED') AS stopped_count, 
  sum(current_status = 'RUNNING') as running_count
from tbl
group by system_id
```

Boolean is automatically reduced to integer in MySQL

Output:

```
| SYSTEM_ID | STOPPED_COUNT | RUNNING_COUNT |
|-----------|---------------|---------------|
|        49 |             1 |             1 |
|        50 |             1 |             1 |
|        51 |             0 |             1 |
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3bcc/2

If the COUNT(or any aggregation function for that matter) come from LEFT JOIN, you have to enclose the results with COALESCE or ISNULL:

```
select system_id, 
  isnull( sum(current_status = 'STOPPED') , 0 ) AS stopped_count, 
  isnull( sum(current_status = 'RUNNING') , 0 ) as running_count
from tbl
group by system_id
```

ANSI SQL-compliant:

```
select system_id, 
  coalesce( sum(current_status = 'STOPPED') , 0 ) AS stopped_count, 
  coalesce( sum(current_status = 'RUNNING') , 0 ) as running_count
from tbl
group by system_id
```

---

Some database are a little verbose though. Postgresql: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d3bcc/2

```
select system_id, 
  sum((current_status = 'STOPPED')::int) AS stopped_count, 
  sum((current_status = 'RUNNING')::int) as running_count
from tbl
group by system_id
```

Other database: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d3bcc/2

```
select system_id, 
  count(case when current_status = 'STOPPED' then 1 end) AS stopped_count, 
  count(case when current_status = 'RUNNING' then 1 end) as running_count
from tbl
group by system_id
```

Comment: Thanks, this almost works for me. There is one little detail, though. There are some systems which may not be listed in the table, but still have to be listed in the end result (LEFT OUTER JOIN), but when I do this with your method, the result for those is NULL and not 0. Do you have any idea of why? Still, I can at least work this out now. Very helpful trick!

Comment: That really happens with LEFT JOIN. You have to enclose the final result to COALESCE or ISNULL. I'll show in the answer, I'll edit it

Answer (score 1):

```
select system_id, 
IF( if(currentstaus = 'RUNNING',0.5,0) + if(currentstaus = 'STOPPED',0.5,0)=1,1,0) 
AS status_count from table_name group by system_id
```

Try this query and tell me if it works or not.

Comment: This assumes that the only possible statuses are 'RUNNING' and 'STOPPED', what if there are more? :)

Comment: @elite5472 i didn't know the possibilities of other occurrences so i made it in this way you can modify it according to your need

Comment: Servers can submit 256^32 possible statuses to my database, so that would be kind of difficult :P

Comment: @elite5472 ohh...! that means this would not work in your case